# How to process 400 response in RxJava2

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I am struggling with correct exception handling in RxJava2. I am trying to refresh my token inside an `OkHttp3` interceptor like this:

```
tokenRepository.refreshToken(authStateManager.current.refreshToken!!)
                        .doOnError {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Could not obtain new access token.")

                            authStateManager.signOut()
                        }
                        .subscribe { tokenResponse ->
                            Log.d(TAG, "Obtained new access token: " + tokenResponse.toString())

                            authStateManager.updateAfterTokenResponse(TokenResponse.jsonDeserialize(tokenResponse.toString()), null)

                            token = authStateManager.current.accessToken
                        }
```

It works nicely if the refresh token is valid and the request returns 200. But if the refresh token is invalidated and I get some error code (for example 400), the `doOnError` block is executed but it then proceeds to the subscribe block where the following exception is thrown:

```
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 400 
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:54)
        at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:37)
...
```

I tried using `onErrorReturn` and `onErrorResumeNext` but I would like to skip the subscribe block completely (it there is an error, just log user out and don't try to do anything). Is it possible? The `refreshToken` method returns `Single<JsonObject>` type of response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use the `onError` in the subscription? I like using RxKotlin for this. For example, I can do the following:

```
.subscribeBy(onSuccess = {
     // do Something in on success
}, onError = {
     // do something in onError
})
```

So in your case, it could be something like:

```
tokenRepository.refreshToken(authStateManager.current.refreshToken!!)
    .subscribeBy(onSuccess = {
        Log.d(TAG, "Obtained new access token: " + it.toString())
        authStateManager.updateAfterTokenResponse(TokenResponse.jsonDeserialize(it.toString()), null)
        token = authStateManager.current.accessToken
    }, onError = {
        Log.w(TAG, "Could not obtain new access token.")
        // the variable "it" here is a throwable which means you can determine if it's a RetrofitException and what status code is returned
    })
```

However, if you do not want to use RxKotlin, you can handle your Rx subscriptions like this in Kotlin:

```
.subscribe({ Log.d(TAG, "Obtained new access token: " + it.toString()) },
           { Log.e(TAG, "Error is ${it.message}") })
```

You can handle the error in the second part of the function where the `Log.e` is being used.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this in my scenario. Could you explain it in my usecase how to modify my subscriber?

Comment: Yeah sure. First of all, add the RxKotlin dependency to your gradle build. Then change subscribe section with subscribeBy. I'll modify my answer above.

Comment: I would love to stick to RxJava... I would have to modify a big part of my application and I am sure that this could be done without other dependencies.

Comment: Yes you can if you replace subscribeBy with subscribe (you'll have to remove the onSuccess and onError words, but the principles and structure is the same. Also, RxKotlin is not an overwrite of RxJava - it's a very small library that has some small features that makes writing RxJava code more readable in Kotlin - because at the end of the day - RxJava is written for Java; not Kotlin

Comment: @Smajl I've added a little except at the bottom of the answer that uses pure RxJava in Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem but I fixed it now. I don't know if my explanation is correct but it seems like `doOnError` doesn't handle the exception.

You need to use the `subscribe()` method that takes an `onError` `Consumer` as a parameter and handle the error there:

```
subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onSuccess, Consumer<? super Throwable> onError)
```

In Java it would look like this:

```
.subscribe(tokenResponse -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "Obtained new access token: " + tokenResponse.toString());
                authStateManager.updateAfterTokenResponse(TokenResponse.jsonDeserialize(tokenResponse.toString()), null);
                token = authStateManager.current.accessToken;
            }, throwable -> {
                Log.w(TAG, "Could not obtain new access token.");
                authStateManager.signOut();
            }));
```